# Can't use custom listView and adapter with listFragment in swipe view

Tags: android

please i need your help i try to solve this problem since 5 days. i try to use ListFragment with custom view on my view parger. But i receive a error when tab of ListFragment is actived. i speak french so please if i have mistake.
this is my error

```
08-01 22:46:13.387: E/AndroidRuntime(8452): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

an here my listFragment class:

```
public class MomentFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceBundle){

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(R.array.pref_light_color);
        CustomMomentListViewAdapter aa = new CustomMomentListViewAdapter(getActivity());

        setListAdapter(aa);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_core_moment, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    }

    public static MomentFragment newInstance(){

        MomentFragment fragment = new MomentFragment();

        return fragment;

    }

}
```

Here is my customAdapter class

```
public class CustomMomentListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private List<Integer> mModel = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomMomentListViewAdapter(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mModel.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mModel.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        CustomMomentListView v = null;

        /* if view doesn't exist we create it */
        if(convertView == null){

            v = new CustomMomentListView(mContext);

        }else{
            v = (CustomMomentListView) convertView;
        }

        v.bind(getItem(position));

        return v;
    }

    public void bind(List<Integer> model){
        mModel = model;
    }

}
```

and this is my custom list view (custom_moment_list_view.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/moment_item_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/moment_empty" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

and finally source of view which use in onCreate function of listFragment (fragment_core_moment.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/moment_empty" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you use a ListFragment, you have to use a view with an id of android.R.id.list, according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)

Comment: ListFragment gives you some nice things for free, but, in most cases, you probably want to make your own Fragment.

Comment: Try to move your onActivity created code to onCreateView method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your this code to `onCreteView()` method from `onActivityCreated()`

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(R.string.text);
CustomMomentListViewAdapter aa = new CustomMomentListViewAdapter(getActivity());
aa.bind(list);
setListAdapter(aa);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I try your solution but i have the same error

Comment: I have edited my post with updated code so please see my update in the MomentFragment class @PiYusH GuPtA

Comment: @angel I think code seems like right though you facing same problem mail me this demo project i will check now.

Comment: my project work on API level 20, can i send you always the demo at your mail adress ?

Comment: And just change your API LEVEL to 19 because in 20 your graphical layout doesn't load

Comment: hi @PiYusH GuPtA it's work now i created new project and i use your answer. now it's work perfectly. Thank, thank and great thank my friend for yor great help. my project can continue now !!